# What's the best way to get image color analysis data in React?

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, html5-canvas

I want to get pixel-by-pixel color data for an image so I can adapt it into a "8-bit" sort of look using a grid of colored squares.

From the research I've done so far, it looks like the standard way to get that kind of data is using an HTML5 canvas and context.getImageData ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/xLF38/)). So far though I've had no luck getting this to work in a React app.

The closest I've gotten is this. I'm sure there are a million things wrong with it, probably to do with how I'm interacting with the DOM, but it at least returns an imageData object. The problem is that the color value for every pixel is 0.

***Updated*** to use ref instead of getElementById

```
function App() {
  const imgRef = useRef(null);
  const img = <img ref={imgRef} src={headshot} />;

  // presumably we want to wait until after render?
  useEffect(() => {
    if (imgRef === null) {
      console.log("image ref missing");
      return;
    }
    if (imgRef.current === null) {
      console.log("image ref is null");
      return;
    }
    // couldn't use imgRef.current.offsetHeight/Width for these because typscript 
    // thinks imgRef.current is `never`?
    const height = 514; 
    const width = 514;
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = height; canvas.width = width;
    const context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (context === null) {
      console.log(`context or image missing`);
      return
    }
    context.drawImage(imgRef.current, 0, 0);
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    console.log(`Image Data`, imageData);
  }, []);

  return img; 
}
```

Related: ultimately I want to get this data without actually displaying the image, so any tips on that would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could likely solve the mounted problem by passing a `ref` to the image and accessing `ref.current` in the `useEffect` hook. `document.getElementById` should ideally be avoided in React

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I had tried that in earlier iterations with no luck. Updated the code in my question to use a ref, but sadly the result is the same.

Comment: You're not waiting for the image to have loaded before attempting to access it... Let me write up something for that.

Comment: In addition, you are only running the `useEffect` hook once, because you pass it an empty array of dependencies. You likely want to remove that dependency array, or pass `ref.current` to it. This will require you to ensure you don't redraw the canvas if it's already present (which can also be checked with a `ref`)

Comment: @AKX thanks! I'd thought putting everything in useEffect would have taken care of that. What have I misunderstood there?

Comment: @AKX That was it! I'd thought passing an empty set of dependencies made the useEffect run once, after everything had rendered. Giving it a dependency on imgRef.current make it work!

Comment: @usernamenumber A dependency on `imgRef.current` will not always work. Refs changing _do not_ cause components to update; in any case, the ref could be for an image element whose image has yet to load.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this now without actually displaying the image? If I give it `display: none`, I'm back to all 0s in the image analysis, which makes sense but surely there's a way to analyze an image without displaying it?

Comment: Sure - the `new Image()` constructor. I'll augment my answer...

Comment: There we go, please see my answer & edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for the image to load. (As with regular HTML, that happens asynchronously.)

So, instead of using an effect that's run as soon as the component has mounted, hook it up to your image's `onLoad`. Aside from that:

- You don't need to check whether `imgRef` is null; the ref box itself never is.
- When using TypeScript and DOM refs, use `useRef<HTML...Element>(null);` to have `ref.current` have the correct type.
- There is no need to make `imgRef.current` a dependency for the handler, since refs changing do not cause components to update.

```
export default function App() {
  const imgRef = React.useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);

  const readImageData = React.useCallback(() => {
    const img = imgRef.current;
    if (!img?.width) {
      return;
    }
    const { width, height } = img;
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.width = width;
    const context = canvas.getContext?.("2d");
    if (context === null) {
      return;
    }
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    console.log(`Image Data`, imageData);
  }, []);

  return <img ref={imgRef} src={kitten} onLoad={readImageData} />;
}
```

## EDIT

> Do you know how I can do this now without actually displaying the image?

To read an image without actually showing it in the DOM, you'll need `new Image` - and then you *can* use an effect.

```
/** Promisified image loading. */
function loadImage(src: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => {
      resolve(img);
    });
    img.addEventListener("error", reject);
    img.src = src;
  });
}

function analyzeImage(img: HTMLImageElement) {
  const { width, height } = img;
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.width = width;
  const context = canvas.getContext?.("2d");
  if (context === null) {
    return;
  }
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  console.log(`Image Data`, imageData);
}

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadImage(kitten).then(analyzeImage);
  }, []);
  return <>hi</>;
}
```

Comment: So one huge-take-away from this for me should be that useEffect runs after the page renders, but that just means after React has created html and fed it to the browser. Images and anything else that might load asynchronously can _not_ be assumed to have loaded just because useEffect is running. Is that right?

Comment: As for asynchronous loading, you've nailed it, but in fact, `useEffect` can run even before the DOM has been mutated. `useLayoutEffect` fires after DOM mutations have landed.